# SQL Server Management Studio - using multiple filters in table list?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssms

In Management Studio, you can right click on the tables group to create a filter for the table list. Has anyone figured out a way to include multiple tables in the filter? For example, I'd like all tables with "`br_*`" and "`tbl_*`" to show up.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be able to roll your own addon to SMSS that would allow you to do what you are looking for:

[The Black Art of Writing a SQL Server Management Studio 2005 Add-In](http://jcooney.net/post/2007/11/26/The-Black-Art-of-Writing-a-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2005-Add-In.aspx)

[Extend Functionality in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio with Add-ins](http://aspalliance.com/1374_Extend_Functionality_in_SQL_Server_2005_Management_Studio_with_Addins.all)

The first one is specifically for searching and displaying all schema objects with a given name so you might be able to expand upon that for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 45):

**No**, you can't do this. When we first got Management Studio I've tried every possible combination of everything you could think of: `_`, `%`, `*`, `"`, `'`, `&&`, `&`, `and`, `or`, `|`, `||`, etc...

Comment: For such a popular piece of software with such huge licensing costs, SQL Management Studio suffers from some quite fundamental limitations. This is only the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Management Studio is a free software that comes along with SQL Server license.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v17.1 and it has a SQL injection bug in it's filter construction, so you can actually escape default

```
tbl.name like '%xxx%'
```

and write your own query (with some limitations). For example to filter tables that are ending with "_arch", "_hist", "_purge" I used following filter value

```
_arch') and RIGHT(tbl.name, 5) != N'purge' and RIGHT(tbl.name, 4) != N'hist' and not(tbl.name like N'bbb
```

You can use SQL Server Profiler to see the constructed query and adjust it as needed.

Not sure if this same bug is available in previous SQL Management Studio versions or when it will be fixed, but for now I'm happy with the result.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed as of 17.5. I can escape the filter and inject additional conditions without SSMS throwing an error, but it doesn't return any valid results.

Answer (score 2):

At first it looks like it could use a `CONTAINS` query (e.g. `"br_*" OR "tbl_*"`), but it doesn't seem to. It seems to only support a value that is then passed into a `LIKE` clause (e.g. `'app'` becomes `'%app%'`).

Answer (score 2):

I've used Toad for SQL Server (freeware version) which has very nice filtering options.

Answer (score 2):

The "sql injection" method still works (v17.5), but with a twist:

```
zzzz' or charindex('pattern1',  name) > 0  or charindex('pattern2', name) > 0 or name like 'zzzz
```

(I used the 'zzzz' to bypass the '%')

It doesn´t work if '_' or '%' is used in the patterns (or anywhere on your code), because it will automatically be replaced by '[_]' or '[%]' before evaluation.

Comment: Unable to get it to work using SSMS 19.1.  I receive no errors however I also get no results.  zzzz' or charindex('pattern1',  Table1Name) > 0  or charindex('pattern2', Table2Name) > 0 or name like 'zzzz.  I also tried: zzzz' or charindex('Table1Name',  name) > 0  or charindex('Table2Name', name) > 0 or name like 'zzzz.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you cannot do this in SQL Server Management Studio (up and including 2014).

The following query will give you a filtered list of tables, if this is all you need:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME) AS TABLE_SCHEMA_AND_NAME,
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z') -- schemas go here
ORDER BY
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score -1):

The SQL injection method still works (somewhat) as of SSMS 2017 v17.8.1, although it puts brackets around the `%` symbol, so it will interpret those literally.

If you're using the Name->Contains filter, Profiler shows:
... `AND dtb.name LIKE N'%MyDatabase1%')`

So, in the Name->Contains field: `MyDatabase1') OR (dtb.name LIKE 'MyDatabase2` should do it for simple cases.

Comment: I can't get this working in 18.5.1. The query ends up looking like: and dtb.name like N'%dbname1'''') OR (dtb.name LIKE ''''Adbname%')

Answer (score -3):

Your in luck, I just conquered that feat, although my success is small because you can filter by schema which would allow you see more than 1 table but you have to type the filter text in each time you want to change it.

Answer (score -3):

This is old I know, but it's good to know that it can works if you input just entering the "filter" text. Skip `*` or `%` or any other standard search characters, just enter `br_` or `tbl_` or whatever you want to filter on.